# Elementary abelian $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How can we show that if $N$ is abelian and $C_G(N)=N$, then $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$?

Comment: What is $G$? Any group?

Answer (score 1):

Not true, consider an odd prime $p$, the nonabelian group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p^{2}$:
$$
G = \langle a, b : a^{p^{2}} = 1, b^{p} = 1, b^{-1} a b = a^{1+p} \rangle
$$
and let $N = \langle a \rangle$. Then $C_{G}(N) = N$, but $N$ is cyclic of order $p^{2}$.

Comment: Let $G$ be a non-solvable group.Can we say that $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group?

Comment: $PSL(2,7)$ has a self-centralizing cyclic subgroup of order $4$. See for instance Theorem 2 here http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ7_04%2FS1446788700004511a.pdf&code=c177b0f2f2fad3ad0efbe7a12d05dd39